# Sequence of functions: how do I interpret this notation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation, sequence-of-function

I am trying to solve a limit problem for a sequence of functions. My professor defined the sequence as such

$\{u^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty} = \begin{cases} u^0 = 0\\ u^{n+1} = \mathcal{H}(u^n)\\ \end{cases}$

where $\mathcal{H}(u)$ is a linear mapping.

Is this just an alternative to the more common notation

$\{u_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$

The sequence describes different solutions to a linear second order inhomogenous ODE.

Comment: I think it should be interpreted as a geometric sequence with a factor of $u$. The other notation describes an arbitrary sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The common notation for [sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) is to use parentheses instead of braces and subscripts instead of superscripts, that is
$
(u_n)_{n = 0}^\infty \text{ or } (u_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}.
$
The potential danger with the superscript notation is a possible confusion with an exponent. But maybe your professor has some specific reason to prefer the superscript notation in the context of linear second order nonhomogenous differential equations.